# assigned value to local variable inside subscribe()

Tags: angular

I am making `http post` and then trying to assign value to local variable inside subscribe.

However that local variable line of code gets never called. Why ? Whats wrong with my code?

This is my component

```
submitted = false;

    onSubmit() {
    this.leaveService.addLeave(this.model)
        .subscribe(res => {
            this.submitted = true;  **// This line of code never execute. Why?**

        });

    }
```

This is my service

```
addLeave(body: leave): Observable<leave[]> {
let bodyString = JSON.stringify(body); // Stringify payload
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }); // ... Set content type to JSON
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); // Create a request option

return this.http.post(this._apiUrl, body, options)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw('Error'));
}
```

My MVC controller method (Just added simple one to ensure round trip is fine)

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public IActionResult CreateLeaveRequest([FromBody] LeaveModel leave)
{
    return StatusCode(200);
}
```

}

I don't see any error in console. 
Let me know if you need more information to understand the problem.

**Note:**

onSubmit() definitely called. the sequence is it calls OnSubmit(), which calls addLeave from service, that sends the request to controller method (debug point hit) .

Comment: How onSubmit() is called? from the view? please post it. Also what the console.log(res) shows?

Comment: throw `console.log('testing');` after onSubmit to see if the function is even being called.

Comment: Make sure you have an ngSubmit() defined on the form, along with a button within the form assigned to `type="submit"`.

Comment: Check your network tab in debugger, make sure the response you are getting is as expected and the response body is JSON.

Comment: @joshrathke, onSubmit() definitely called. I am not that stupid !! the sequence is it calls OnSubmit(), which calls addLeave from service, that sends the request to controller method (debug point hit) .

Comment: Didn't mean to say you were stupid, I use console log all the time to verify. Just basic troubleshooting. You could try catching the error in your subscription if there is one. To do so just put an `err` handler code block after your `res` codeblock and see if it spits anything out.

Comment: To make it more clear  >>> console.log('blah blah') gets called if i use just before calling addLeave OR after addLeave finish. But it does not hit/called if i put inside subscribe() same case as i said for this.submitted.

Comment: @AndrewStalker, I checked in network tab, Under response tab, i see 'This request has no response data available'. So? I updated my question with server side MVC controller method.

Comment: @simbada what was the http status code. If it was 200 then the server is not sending you data. if its another code then that will indicate another issue. Added some info to my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your .map function needs to return something...

```
return this.http.post(this._apiUrl, body, options)
    .map(res => {
      console.log(res) // Log here to see what you get in response body
      return res.json() || []; // if response has no json then return []
    ) 
    .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw('Error'));
}
```

Comment: `.map(res => res.json())` is equal to `.map(res => {return res.json();})`

Comment: Alternatively to avoid the .map issue entirely unless there is something custom going on, he could just use the `HttpClientModule` and completely forgo mapping the output to json, as the new client already does it for you.

Comment: @Andrew you spotted well and it resolved my issue. Thanks you! Since, I was not returning JSON response from my MVC controller hence this line in my service ---“.map(res => res.json())”--- was failing and as result subscribe() was not being actually subscribed / called. This is the reason that line –“this.submitted”--- inside subscribe() was never hit. But I wonder about one thing, for HTTP POST operations it is not always necessary to return JSON response back to client because you may could just return HTTPStatusCode like I was doing.

Comment: @Andrew Just asking did you come across this scenario? I am not sure what the best practice is whether to always return JSON response or put null check on client side. Hope you get my point.

Comment: @simbada Not had an issue not getting JSON yet, however in the project I'm currently working on, we do the null check as standard practice.

Answer (score 1):

This first function passed into the subscribe is executed when the Observable emits an item. If the post does not return a value and you don't manually map a response, no item is emitted and this function is not executed:

```
    .subscribe(res => {
        this.submitted = true;  **// This line of code never execute. Why?**

    });
```

You need to either emit an item from the Observable or you could try using the third argument of the subscribe and execute the code upon completion instead of upon emit.

```
    .subscribe(
        () => {},               **// On emit
        err => {},              **// On error
        () => {
          this.submitted = true;  **// On complete **
    });
```

Comment: Hi @DeborahK, thanks for your detailed reply. However I don’t think so you are quite correct. The actual problem was I was not returning JSON response from server to called (client) and hence his line in my service ---“.map(res => res.json())”--- was failing and as result subscribe() was not being actually subscribed / called. Andrea Stalker identified it quite well and it resolved my issue. I am happy to look for more from your side if that can improve my understanding. Cheers